# Change label to textbox for edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Have a look at this example first, 
[click here](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/editupdatedelete-user-account-details.html). I want you to see only the example of how he changed a label into text box after he hits edit.I want to make edit profile page but I don't want to use bind grid view. Is there any possible ways to retrieve some data from table in database to be shown in labels then when uset hits the edit button, the label will change to textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why do you need to show a label ? 
you can show it in a text box and set IsReadOnly or ReadOnly to true, set style to flat and remove border(it'll appear like a label), and then on the Edit Action, you can change this ReadOnly/Editable property.

Comment: The textbox does not adjusting height to the content (label does). How we can handle this? Second, when I use multiline for textbox it displays two lines even one is filled. Complete mess.